# How to merge all of the output lists into one list

Tags: python, list, loops, output, flatten

I was trying the following code snippet for a project of mine:

```
scrap=['Theodore von Kármán Lecture', 'Science Journey: "The Origin of Photosynthesis: A Window into the Intricate Relationship Between Life and the World Around It"', 'Science Journey: "Addressing Energy Storage Challenges: Making Electrolytes That Can Help Batteries Store More Energy"', 'Science Journey: "Defects in Crystals: The Tiniest Engineering Tool"']

for i in scrap:
    words_in_scrap = i.split() 
    # print("words_in_scrap=",words_in_scrap) 
    for j in words_in_scrap:
      words = j.lower()
      # print(words)
      for k in words: 
        # print(k)
        if k in punc:
          words = words.replace(k,"")
          # print(words)
      # print(k)
      clean = words      #corrected lot
      # print(clean)
      c_list = []
      c_list.append(clean)
      print(c_list)
```

I got this output:

```
['theodore']
['von']
['kármán']
['lecture']
['science']
['journey']
['the']
['origin']
['of']
['photosynthesis']
['a']
['window']
['into']
['the']
['intricate']
['relationship']
['between']
['life']
['and']
['the']
['world']
['around']
['it']
['science']
['journey']
['addressing']
['energy']
['storage']
['challenges']
['making']
['electrolytes']
['that']
['can']
['help']
['batteries']
['store']
['more']
['energy']
['science']
['journey']
['defects']
['in']
['crystals']
['the']
['tiniest']
['engineering']
['tool']
```

I want all of these output lists to be put into one list, like:

> ['theodore','von','karman','science',.............]

I understand that these individual outputs were produced due to loops, I've tried to do .append() for doing this and ended up with the c_list and they turned out to be independent lists. Any solution to this will be highly valued and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scrap=['Theodore von Kármán Lecture', 'Science Journey: "The Origin of Photosynthesis: A Window into the Intricate Relationship Between Life and the World Around It"', 'Science Journey: "Addressing Energy Storage Challenges: Making Electrolytes That Can Help Batteries Store More Energy"', 'Science Journey: "Defects in Crystals: The Tiniest Engineering Tool"']
punc = [".","/",":"]
c_list = []
for i in scrap:
    words_in_scrap = i.split() 
    # print("words_in_scrap=",words_in_scrap) 
    for j in words_in_scrap:
      words = j.lower()
      # print(words)
      for k in words: 
        # print(k)
        if k in punc:
          words = words.replace(k,"")
          # print(words)
      # print(k)
      clean = words      #corrected lot
      # print(clean)

      c_list.append(clean)

print(c_list)
```

I assumes `punc` is tab list of punctuation.

Is this working for you ?

output :

> ['theodore', 'von', 'kármán', 'lecture', 'science', 'journey:',
> '"the', 'origin', 'of', 'photosynthesis:', 'a', 'window', 'into',
> 'the', 'intricate', 'relationship', 'between', 'life', 'and', 'the',
> 'world', 'around', 'it"', 'science', 'journey:', '"addressing',
> 'energy', 'storage', 'challenges:', 'making', 'electrolytes', 'that',
> 'can', 'help', 'batteries', 'store', 'more', 'energy"', 'science',
> 'journey:', '"defects', 'in', 'crystals:', 'the', 'tiniest',
> 'engineering', 'tool"']

Comment: Yep, worked great, I must've added that c_list=[] at the start! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at those 3 statements, each executed on each iteration of the loop:

```
c_list = []
c_list.append(clean)
print(c_list)
```

So for every word, you are creating a new list, putting that word into it and then printing it. Instead you want to create a new list before the loop, put all the words you want and then print all of them after the loop is finished.

Comment: Yes! I realize I should have added that c_list=[] before the loops. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Doesnt matter if you append since the line above wipes the lsit clean. Get rid of this like `c_list = []` and put it before the main loop, and put the `print(c_list)` outside and after the main for loop and see if that works.

Comment: you need `c_list = []` so that `c_list.append()` doesn't cause an error. It has to be in a different place though.

Comment: Yes but it shouldnt be right after the append, that means you always append to an empty list and that print that single item list and then in a new iteration wipe it again....

Comment: I know what the code does, but removing c_list definition will break the code even more.

Comment: @matszwecja and yet the first answer that works is written like I said it should???? Hmmmmmmmmm

Comment: You said "Get rid of this like `c_list = []`" and none of the other answers removes the line. It is still there, just in a different place.

Comment: @matszwecja I assume people understand the bare bone basics of the fact that you need to declare a list in order to use it................ Wrong of me to assume that bud, apologies, I edited the answer